# How to show button for each value in list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string list "_choice" and i would like to show a button for each value in "_choice" list. 
I have this error: "the element type Set MaterialButton can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'"

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class QuestionPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String playerName;   final String question;   final List<String> _choice;   final String answer;


  QuestionPage(this.playerName, this.question, this._choice, this.answer);


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        //AppBar
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("$playerName to play", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    ),

      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Question: \n $question'),

                      //------------PROBLEM HERE------------------
                      for (var i = 0; i < _choice.length; i++) {
                      new MaterialButton(
                        minWidth: 120.0,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        onPressed: null,
                        child: new Text(_choice[i],
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),),
                      ),
                      }

                      ]   ))))]

    )} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the for-loop curly brackets.

You need to change this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < _choice.length; i++) {
          new MaterialButton(
            minWidth: 120.0,
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            onPressed: null,
            child: new Text(_choice[i],
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white
              ),),
          ),
          }
```

to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _choice.length; i++)
  new MaterialButton(
    minWidth: 120.0,
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
    onPressed: null,
    child: new Text(_choice[i],
      style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          color: Colors.white
      ),
      ),
  ),
```